# unable to connect to another computer through the Internet using ssh?

Tags: ssh, connection

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 on my laptop which I would like to use to connect to my Ubuntu 16.04.1 desktop. I installed the OpenSSH server on the desktop machine and laptop.

```
$ ssh user@ip address
ssh: connect to host ip address port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Are they on the same network?

Comment: what does ping ip_address show?

Comment: they are on the different network

Answer (score 0):

If you have this laptop on a home network, you need to enable and set port forwarding on the router for that network. Namely, you need to port forward port 22 from your laptop making it available to 0.0.0.0/0 (no restrictions). Make sure you have a strong password, the Internet starts hammering open port 22's pretty quickly.

Comment: i'm not using router and using different connections for both laptop and desktop.

Comment: what connections?

Comment: different ethernet cables connected.

Comment: Are they directly connected? Did you use a crossover ethernet cable to do so? Many devices are auto sensing, but not all. What is the topology of your network between these two devices? Can you ping the other host, and it responds successfully? Did you start sshd on the one you want to ssh into? Same subnets?

Comment: desktop is connected to ethernet cable and laptop is connected via usb tethering (android).

Comment: Ah, that's a bit different then. If your wifi is not connected on your phone, you are essentially trying to ssh to your desktop from the open Internet. You will need to set up port forwarding on your router for this. Port forward port 22 from any ip address to the private ip of your desktop. If your wifi is connected, then you are trying to ssh from any other host on your internal network. If wifi off, or on? What model of router do you have?

Comment: i don't use any router only ethernet cable and i use mobile data for the laptop.

Comment: What does the other end of the ethernet cable connect to from your desktop?

Comment: i did not understand your question.

Comment: The ethernet cable that is plugged into your desktop, what is plugged into the other end of the cable? What is the topology of your network, what devices do you have and how is everything interconnected?

Comment: i don't know which it is connected to and i just have ethernet cable and it belongs to internet service provider.

Comment: Does it come straight out of the wall, or does it plug into a modem? For example, my network has my laptop, which connects to the wireless router, and that plugs into a small modem, which then goes into the wall and to the isp's network. I need to know what the network looks like and is between your laptop's wireless tethering, and your laptop. The traffic goes out to the internet from your tether, then it is coming into your house, what devices does it traverse?

Comment: Is the ethernet cable coming straight out of your wall from your ISP? This link to an image may help explain my question: https://sketchboard.me/bAfqZubCOFwL

Comment: my laptop is connected via USB tethering of Mobile data (carrier network).

Comment: my desktop is connected to ethernet cable.

Comment: where does the ethernet cable from your desktop connect to?